# My infix is whole and my whole is cold

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My prefix is a winner.
>
> My suffix is the inner.
>
> My infix is whole.
>
> My whole is cold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Winter

My prefix is a winner.

> **Win**

My suffix is the inner.

> **Inter** - a prefix used to mean "between"

My infix is whole.

> **Int** - short for integer in computer programming, i.e, a *whole* number

My whole is cold.

> **Winter** is the coldest season.

Answer (score 1):

> Passionless

Prefix

> Prefix "pass", what the winner has done to everyone else in a race

Suffix

> Suffix "less", a number less than x is inside the set of natural numbers up to x

Infix

> Infix "ion", a perfectly whole bit of matter, though I grant the missing electron may make this a stretch

The whole

> Passionless means "cold or unemotional"